# How do I Automate the creation of Azure Repos?

Tags: python, git, azure, automation, repository

So far ive figured out how to create an azure repo with python. My code is below. I am having trouble figuring out how to delete repos with python. Then I need to automate the entire process.  Here is what i have so far.

```py
import subprocess


def run_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return output, error


output, error = run_command('az repos create --name="newnewchris" --organization="https://dev.azure.com/iDevOpsio/" --project="iDevOps.io"')
print(output)
print(error)

output, error = run_command('git clone https://iDevOpsio@dev.azure.com/iDevOpsio/iDevOps.io/_git/chrisnewnew')
print(output)
print(error)

output, error = run_command('git remote add origin https://iDevOpsio@dev.azure.com/iDevOpsio/iDevOps.io/_git/chrisnewnew')
print(output)
print(error)

output, error = run_command('git push -u origin --all')
print(output)
print(error)
```

Comment: What is the specific issue you're encountering? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error message. If the program's behavior is different than what you are expecting, what happens and what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/
It looks to be a python wrapper for Azure CLI.  Azure CLI has az repo.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos?view=azure-cli-latest

So Then you can use that to create the repo, and use git to push updates.
https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html